# Change string from hard coded to string resources in Android Studio inside a switch statement

Tags: android, android-fragments, switch-statement

Hello guys i want to change the string values inside my switch statement from hard coded string to the string i have declared in string resources. I am inside a Fragment page Adapter.

```
 @Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            return  "Museums";
        case 1:
            return "Culture";
        case 2:
            return "Food";
        default:
            return "Views";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call strings from `string.xml` file by using

> getResources().getString(int resID);

but you can't access `getResources()` directly as you are in the fragment

so you need to get a context by Passing it as a Parameter to Constructor

```
Context mContext; // first declare variable 
public className(Context mContext){
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

so the final call can be `mContext.getResources().getString(int resID);`

Comment: good, I see now it is solved I 'll edit the answer thanks @cricket_007 **edited**

Comment: When i add this to change my hard coded strings it says cannot resolve method getActivity()

Comment: @Houxe Apologize for late, you can pass Context as a parameter in constructor Look to edit answer

Comment: Thank you very much mate you really helped me!!

Comment: Actually when i pass it as a parameter inside 
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position, Context mContext) {
} it says that it's not overrided by the parent class

Comment: thanks .. but try to pass it to object of the class only not every time you call the method as it usually will be with you in all other class methods

Comment: After i pass it to the constructor and when i declare it as an object at the main activity it gives me an error TourGuideViewPager categoryViewPager = new TourGuideViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager()); what should i add after getSupportFragmentManager()?

Comment: can you show me current constructor in TourGuideViewPager please?

Comment: public TourGuideViewPager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);


    }

Comment: public TourGuideViewPager(FragmentManager fm, Context mContext ) { super(fm); this.mContext = mContext;}

then you can use it normally in other methods you need.